# Write multiple columns on .xls through Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, excel

```
    out_file.write('Position'+'\t'+'Hydrophobic'+'\n')

    for i in position:
        out_file.write(str(i)+'\n')
    for j in value:
        out_file.write('\t'+str(j)+'\n')
```

so it says

```
Position     Hydrophobic
0            a
1            b
2            c

#... and so on
```

when it writes to the excel file it puts it puts the j from value at the bottom of the column of the i in position column

How do i put them side by side with '\t' and '\n'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, j in zip(position, value):
    out_file.write(str(i) + '\t' + str(j) + '\n')
```

or better:

```
     out_file.write('%s\t%s\n' % (str(i), str(j))
```

or better:

```
text = ['%s\t%s' % (str(i), str(j) for i, j in zip(position, value)]
text = '\n'.join(text)
out_file.write(text)
```

Comment: @ joaquin : perfect i knew it was something like that! thanks